# How to get data form website using BeautifulSoup Python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem to get the data from some page. This is part of my code:

```
for result in results:
        street = result.find('p', attrs={'class':'size16'}).text
        records.append((street))  
        print (street)
```

Website:

```
    <div class="media-body pt5 pb10">
     <div class="mb15">
        <span class="map-item-city block mb0 colorgreen">City</span>
        <p class="small mb20">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="size16">street 98<br>phone. 22 721-56-70</p>
     </div>
     <div class="colorblack"><strong>open</strong></div>
     <div class="mb20 size16">Mon.-Fr. 07.30-15.30</div>
     <div class="mb15 ">
```

Result of my code:

```
ul. Bema 2phone. (32) 745 72 66-69 Wroclaw None
ul. 1 Maja 22/Vphone. 537-943-969 Olawa <p class="small mb20 colorgreen">Placowka partnerska</p>
```

I would like to separate or delete the text after a "br" tag. I need only 'street'

```
    <p class="size16">street 98<br>phone. 22 721-56-70</p>
```

Can You help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use previous_sibling like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="media-body pt5 pb10">
     <div class="mb15">
        <span class="map-item-city block mb0 colorgreen">Bronisze</span>
        <p class="small mb20">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="size16">Poznańska 98<br>tel. 22 721-56-70</p>
     </div>
     <div class="colorblack"><strong>Godziny otwarcia</strong></div>
     <div class="mb20 size16">Pn.-Pt. 07.30-15.30</div>
<div class="mb15 ">
"""

result=BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

br = result.find('br')
print (br.previous_sibling)
```

Or if you want to narrow it down a bit:

```
street = result.find('p', attrs={'class':'size16'}).find('br').previous_sibling
print (street)
```

Outputs (in both cases)

```
Poznańska 98
```

From the documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

> .next_sibling and .previous_sibling
>
> You can use .next_sibling and .previous_sibling to navigate between page elements that are on the same level of the parse tree:

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my problem. Unfortunately, this solution does not work properly. This code clones the street name and mixes the remaining results.

Comment: Can you explain some more? Are you calling find() again?

Comment: name = result.find('p', attrs={'class':'small mb20 colorgreen'}).text

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159802/discussion-between-dan-dev-and-bigd).

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="media-body pt5 pb10">
     <div class="mb15">
        <span class="map-item-city block mb0 colorgreen">Bronisze</span>
        <p class="small mb20">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="size16">Poznańska 98<br>tel. 22 721-56-70</p>
     </div>
     <div class="colorblack"><strong>Godziny otwarcia</strong></div>
     <div class="mb20 size16">Pn.-Pt. 07.30-15.30</div>
<div class="mb15 ">
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for html_tag_div in soup.find_all('div', class_ = "media-body pt5 pb10"):

    for html_tag_div_1 in html_tag_div.find_all('div', class_ = "mb15"):

        for html_tag_2 in html_tag_div_1.find_all("p", class_ = "size16"):

            for html_tag_3 in html_tag_2.find("br").previous_siblings:

                print(html_tag_3.get_text())
```